# How to add two ID Sequence Auto Increment In Postgres And Mapping With Hibernate

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

1. I'm Developing small MicroService Using Spring boot.
2. My database Is Postgres and I have a pojo in my service mapping the table.
3. Initially my Table is created with one Primary Key NOT NULL serial.
4. Now I want to add One more column with serial number starting from 6000 and map with my pojo.

---

```
@JsonProperty("id")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY,generator = "order_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "order_seq_gen", sequenceName ="order_id_seq")

    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("state")
    private String state;

    @JsonProperty("user_Id")
    @Column(name = "user_Id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY,generator = "user_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq_gen", sequenceName ="user_id_seq")
    private Integer userId;
```

1. This is My Pojo.
2. The first Id Is creating but the userId Is not creating.
3. Bellow is my Table structure and sequences.

---

This is my create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE public.user 
(   
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),  
  created timestamp without time zone,   
  modified timestamp without time zone,   
  state character varying(255),   
  name text,   
  user_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),   CONSTRAINT user_pkey
PRIMARY KEY (id) 
)
```

---

Below is my sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.user_id_seq   INCREMENT 1   MINVALUE 6001  
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807   START 6000   CACHE 1; 
ALTER TABLE public.user_id_seq   OWNER TO postgres;
```

---

What I'm trying is in my table the column user_id should generate Auto from Base as 6000 and increment each time by 1.

Whenever I call API from my service it is creating new record. But the user_id is not showing anything.

Comment: "IDENTITY" strategy (auto increment) is nothing to do with a SEQUENCE. Use "SEQUENCE" strategy if you want a SEQUENCE. PostgreSQL does support "IDENTITY" by way of SERIAL columns

Comment: Thanks a lot boss it's working..............thanks for spending your valuable time for my problem.